# Regular Expression: How can I convert CSV data to JSON array?

Tags: regex, json, vim, csv, sublimetext2

**How can I convert a csv string to a JSON Array using regular expression?**

i'm trying to use the regex with text editors like Vim or Sublime Text, not with programming language. FYI, the Sublime Text uses the [Boost syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

If I have a set of csv strings like these:

```
"tag1, tag2, tag3"
```

the string above should be formatted like following:

```
["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

---

**(an explanation for the entire contents added...)**

the csv strings are in the middle of the contents like this:

```
...
{"url":"http://osxdaily.com/2007/0ge5/02/quickly-encrypt-a-file-with-openssl",
 "user":"user01","tag_string":"openssl,encrypt",
 "created_at":"2011/04/19 05:49:26 +0000",
 "title":"Quickly encrypt a file with OpenSSL"},  
{"url":"http://staticimport.blogspot.com","user":"user02",
 "tag_string":"command,line,developer,tools,osx",
 "created_at":"2011/04/19 05:42:13 +0000","title":"Mac OS X Lion Command Line Developer Tools staticimport"},    
{"url":"https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action",
 "user":"user_01","tag_string":"ios,development,download",
 "created_at":"2011/04/19 04:47:26 +0000","title":"Apple Developer Download Center"}
...
```

the **tag_string** is the csv string to be converted to JSON Array.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @MattBall I am looking for more general solutions. `named capture` in regex is what i've tried recently. but it's not worked.

Answer (score 4):

In Vim, in three passes:

```
:s/,\s*/", "/g
:s/^/[
:s/$/]
```

Comment: You can do it in two by combining the last two into `:s/^.*$/[&]`

Comment: You can chain commands in vim by using the `|` character as a separator `:s/,\s*/", "/g | s/^.*$/[&]`